# Should There Be A Tag For ReactOS?

Tags: discussion, tags

I posted a question today about ReactOS, and discovered there's no tag for it yet. I did a search for "[reactos](https://superuser.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=reactos)", but only a couple pages of results came up and many of them were for answers not questions so it's not a popular topic at this point in time.

Here are some example questions I scrounged up:

- [Get The VMware Tools SVGA Driver On ReactOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/809000/get-the-vmware-tools-svga-driver-on-reactos)

This question was posted by me today, and is about using ReactOS's SVGA driver install feature
on VMware Player. I would think the best tags for this question would be [reactos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reactos)[vmware-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vmware-player)[drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drivers)

- [Is ReactOS or WINE the more stable replacement for Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/744425/is-reactos-or-wine-the-more-stable-replacement-for-windows-xp/744427#744427)

This question is about the end of XP, and the user is wondering wether they should go with ReactOS, or Linux with Wine.
It's currently tagged as [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)[wine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wine).

- [Is it possible to run Corona SDK on ReactOS or Wine?](https://superuser.com/questions/710495/is-it-possible-to-run-corona-sdk-on-reactos-or-wine)

This question is about running Corona SDK on either ReactOS or Wine. I think it would make more sense to have this
tagged with [reactos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reactos) than [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows).

- [How To Re-install FreeLoader For Restored ReactOS Installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/809057/how-to-re-install-freeloader-for-restored-reactos-installation)

This question is again by me, and is about re-installing the bootloader when restoring, and deploying ReactOS.

- https://superuser.com/questions/809059/use-ramdisk-sys-to-create-a-ramdrive-on-reactos

This one is about creating a software generated ramdrive on ReactOS.

When it comes to tag creation there seems to be 2 approaches:

1. Unless there are lots of questions don't worry about it, because we can manually retro-actively apply them if a need for the tag creation ever arises.
2. Create it, it helps recruit experts, and saves work down the road; it's not like we can't just delete it later.

I understand the logic of both, they both have their merits, and I think they apply best to different types of tags. For example if you go with option one and create a tag for everything that ever gets asked about, things become too spread out, and the tags become useless. However if you always go with option 2 it creates extra work, and prevents addition of potentially useful tags.

In this case we're talking about an operating system tag, and not even a specific release of the operating system, just a generic tag. Tags for every OS under the sun aren't needed, case and point being the [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) and [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) which work generically to prevent tags for every obscure possibility. However ReactOS doesn't fit into those categories so I think it deserves a tag, even if there are very few questions for it at the moment.

If you read this post, and don't weigh in, somewhere in the world a puppy dies. :(

Comment: I think more people need to ask questions before we create a tag for a minimal amount of questions.

Comment: "couple of pages of results" - Mind if I impose, and suggest you link a few of these? I'm leaning *towards* tag creation, but a little push might help.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I edited some in, but there aren't many out there. Many of the search results are for answers not questions.

Comment: One of those questions is closeworthy ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've added 2 new examples, but quantity isn't really my point here. Take MacBuntu for example, it wouldn't make sense to create a tag for it unless there were great demand, because it's just another Linux distro, and so the Linux tag will work for connecting experts to the questions. ReactOS doesn't have that option, because it's not Windows, Linux, or Unix. Even if there was only 1 question about ReactOS, providing a tag for it has no negative effects because unlike questions about obscure linux distros there is nowhere else for ReactOS questions to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a reactos tag makes sense in this case. I'm happy to create the tag, and have created a tag wiki exerpt, and in a bit, a tag wiki entry.

Since I'm dealing with another thing at the moment, feel free to retag